# savings calculations using range sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on calculating savings using two range slider values which have amount per month and years (should multiply with 12 for months). So, multiplying the `month * age * 12` gives me total savings value, which is working fine. But I need to add 3.3% every year, which gives the actual savings value. It should yield a round figure also, so I used `Math.round`

Ex:

> user enters 25 in month slider and 6 in age slider

calculations should be:

> 25 * 6 * 12 =1800 (gives total value for 6 years)

now adding 3.3% every year

> 25 * 6 * 12*0.33=59.4 (interest for 6 years)

now adding both gives you 1859.4 (which should give us a round figure of 2000)

```
var myCounter = new flipCounter('flip-counter', {value:17424, inc:0, pace:1000, auto:true});

    //var smartInc = 0;

    // month
    $("#month").slider({
        range: "max",
        value: 121,
        min: 0,
        max: 332,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $("#inc_value").text(ui.value);
            myCounter.setValue(ui.value * 12 *  $('#age_slider').slider("value") + interest);
        }
    });
    // age
    $("#age").slider({
        range: "max",
        value: 12,
        min: 0,
        max: 18,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $("#pace_value").text(ui.value);
            myCounter.setValue(ui.value * 12 *  $('#month_slider').slider("value") + interest);
        }
    });

    var months = $("#month_slider").slider("value");
    var age = $("#age_slider").slider("value") * 12;
    var interest = months * age * 0.033;
});
```

Comment: Isn't `3.3% = 0.033`? You could use `25 * 6 * 12 * 1.033` to multiply and add those 3.3% in one line.

Comment: here the amount 25 is amount per month so we should multiply by 12 to get the value for 6 years. And how to get the round figure

Comment: Yeah, i misread it. Sorry. I believe the problem here is in the math (got the same values with a calculator). Wouldn't the interest grow through months?  I mean: `1º month = 25 * 1.033  = 25.825`; `2º month = (25.825 + 25) * 1.033 = 51.65`; ...